# ACM in-text citations for specific locations in a lengthy referenced work?

Tags: citation-style

I'm using the ACM citation style format for my paper.  In the text of that paper, I wish to cite particular passages in a 50-page reference, so the reader will not have to wade through the entire thing just to find the relevant material.  How does that work?  For example, would the following be proper?

> We could, of course, compute its value to at least five decimal places, using Algorithm 3.1 on page 39 of [1].

(Several paragraphs later:)

> From Definition 2.1 on page 12 of [1], a *foo-representable* thingy is a thingy that can be exactly represented by a Foo of finite length.

Or should each location have its own entry in the bibliography?

Comment: There is a comment at http://bogost.com/writing/blog/why_i_hate_acm_format/ by I. Bogost (from June 21, 2013) stating that it would be `[1, p. 12]`, but I do not find an authoritative source on that.